# Protractor - I want to write IF ELSE statement DRYer, if possible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Can I D.R.Y this code?  IF the id `invite-user` tag is displayed in the user's profile the user can click to request to play game ELSE a new random user will be selected until the id `invite-user` is displayed in the user's profile.

```
  browser.get("/index").then(function() {
   element.all(by.css('game-player')).get(randomUser).click();
   browser.sleep(sleep);
element(by.id('invite-user')).isDisplayed().then(function(clickUser) {
  if (clickUser) {
    element(by.id('invite-user')).click();
    element(by.id('role')).sendKeys('Player');
    button.click();
    browser.sleep(sleep);
    expect(element(by.id('pending-admin-approval')).first().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

  } else {
    browser.get("/index").then(function() {
      element.all(by.css('game-player')).get(randomUser).click();
      browser.sleep(sleep);
      element(by.id('invite-user')).click();
      element(by.id('role')).sendKeys('Player');
      button.click();
      browser.sleep(sleep);
      expect(element(by.id('pending-admin-approval')).first().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

    });
  }
});
```

`});`

Comment: Put the common code in a function? I'm not clear on what the issue is. Also, codereview is a better place for this than SO.

Comment: can u please accept the answer if it's fit to your need please? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.get("/index").then(function() {
    element.all(by.css('game-player')).get(randomUser).click();
    browser.sleep(sleep);
    element(by.id('invite-user')).isDisplayed().then(function(clickUser) {
        if (clickUser) {
            inviteUser();

        } else {
            browser.get("/index").then(function() {
                element.all(by.css('game-player')).get(randomUser).click();
                browser.sleep(sleep);

                inviteUser();
            });
        }
    });

    function inviteUser(){
        element(by.id('invite-user')).click();
        element(by.id('role')).sendKeys('Player');
        button.click();
        browser.sleep(sleep);
        expect(element(by.id('pending-admin-approval')).first().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: lamisti I pulled away to another project. code works! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

More Optimised Approach :

```
    browser.get("/index").then(function() {
        element.all(by.css('game-player')).get(randomUser).click();
        waitForApi();
        element(by.id('invite-user')).isDisplayed().then(function(clickUser) {
            if (clickUser) {
                inviteUser();
                return; // Don't go further 
            }

            browser.get("/index").then(function() {
                element.all(by.css('game-player')).get(randomUser).click();
                waitForApi();
                inviteUser();
            });

        });

        function inviteUser(){
            element(by.id('invite-user')).click();
            element(by.id('role')).sendKeys('Player');
            button.click();
            waitForApi();
            expect(element(by.id('pending-admin-approval')).first().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        }
```

Need for this function : For example, if we set 2000 (i.e. 2 seconds) in browser.sleep then there would two cases : 1. API took more time than 2s then Test case would fail 2. API took lesser time than 2s then we have to wait unnecessarily. So to overcome this problem i would suggest to make a check on element we show/hide when API is executed successfully

```
        function waitForApi(){
            let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
            // Waits for the api loader to be no longer visible
            browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element(by.css('#test > .loader'))), 10000); // TODO : Change the condition as per visibility/invisibilty of element in your project
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please also explain how the code tackles the OP's concern

Comment: @Yash : The original question **Protractor - I want to write IF ELSE statement DRYer, if possible** & i made the solution more dryer and also suggested to do browser.wait() rather than browser.sleep(). 
For example, if we set 2000 (i.e. 2 seconds) in browser.sleep then there would two cases : 
1. API took more time than 2s then Test case would fail
2. API took lesser time than 2s then we have to wait unnecessarily.
So to overcome this problem i would suggest to make a check on element we show/hide when API is executed successfully.

Comment: You should make the explanation a part of the answer itself. :)

Comment: Sure, Thankyou :) actually i am newbie to SO. Thanks for suggesting. Please like and upvote if you agree/like the solution :)